# Program hangs after docker-compose up command for django app

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run a simple django app through a docker container, using docker-compose. Everything works perfectly down to when I insert the commands 'docker-compose up', which then performs system checks, has no issue, but then hangs. Because of this, when I go to the browser 'https://localhost:8000', it says this site cant be reached.

[image]

Here is also a snap of my work environment. I am on a windows 10 home edition, thus I work using a docker toolbox.

[image]

Comment: can you share you docker compose file and relevant server codes?

Comment: Did you tried this `docker-compose up -d`, if not then try this and check the container logs

Comment: it just took a long time to load, it works when I put the vm's IP address before the port number.